# Display only non secure websites in Google Search Results

Tags: http, ssl, search

I am looking to find a number of non secure websites with http rather than https, is there any way of displaying only non secure results in the results page of Google or any other search engines? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to find websites that don't have SSL? The only reasons I can think of for specifically wanting to search for sites that have worse security is for nefarious purposes.

Comment: I work for a digital marketing company and would like to find a list of unsecure sites to contact, that's all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes for a particular domain you can use

site:domain.com -inurl:https

This will show you all the non secure pages within the domain.

If you want to display the secure page for domain.com you can use below in google search results:

site:domain.com -inurl:http